# Aligning Image Caption

Tags: html, image, css, text

Currently, I have a problem with an image slideshow caption not positioning itself relative to the parent container. This may be a simple fix with the DIV floating but for the life of me I can't figure it out. The problem is the text does not stay within the constraints of the container that houses the image; and as such transforms differently upon resizing the webpage (basically moves off the visible area of the page). I'm hoping to set the height of the container housing the text to that of the parent container (the one housing the image) before formatting it to stay at the top 1/3 of the image in the center of the page. The text is based in an UL and transitions between items on the list as an overlay over the image.

[This is the code on Codepen.](https://codepen.io/SpazSuper/pen/MORpPV/)As seen when the CSS transitions the Text (and the white background used for example) both are outside the bounds of the .container DIV (the UL with the dropshadow where I'm hoping to constrain the Text to.

Any help would be grately appreciated.

This is the HTML

```
<div class="container" >
<ul class="imageBanner">
<li>
<span>Image 01</span>
<div>
<h2>Ahoy.</h2>
</div>
</li>
<li><span>Image 02</span>
<div>
<h2>Welcome.</h2>
</div></li>
<li><span>Image 03</span>
<div>
<h2>Bonjour.</h2>
</div></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

This is the CSS

```
    .container {
  /* Full height*/
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 5px #888888;
    background:#ccc;
}


/* Image Slideshow Banner */


.imageBanner li span {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   color: transparent;
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: 30%;
   background-repeat: none;
   opacity: 0;
   z-index: 0;
   animation: imageAnimation 18s linear infinite 0s;
 }
 .imageBanner li div {
     z-index: 1;
     position: absolute;
     top:0px;
     width: 100%;
     text-align: center;
     opacity: 0;
     animation: titleAnimation 18s linear infinite 0s;
 }
 .imageBanner li div h2 {

     font-family:Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
     background: #fff;
     font-size: 7em;
     color: rgb(46,105,163);

     line-height: 6em;
 }
.imageBanner li:nth-child(1) span {
 background-image: url('./images/iron_giant.jpg');
}
.imageBanner li:nth-child(2) span {
   background-image: url("./images/lonely_island.jpg");
   animation-delay: 6s;
}
.imageBanner li:nth-child(3) span {
   background-image: url("./images/mountain_range.jpg");
   animation-delay: 12s;
}

.imageBanner li:nth-child(2) div {
   animation-delay: 6s;
}
.imageBanner li:nth-child(3) div {
   animation-delay: 12s;
}
   @keyframes imageAnimation {
     0% { opacity: 0; animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
     8% { opacity: 1; animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
     17% { opacity: 1 }
     35% { opacity: 0 }
     100% { opacity: 0 }
 }
 @keyframes titleAnimation {
     0% { opacity: 0 }
     8% { opacity: 1 }
     17% { opacity: 1 }
     35% { opacity: 0 }
     100% { opacity: 0 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a little hard to find out what final result you seek without a live example, but every time your child elements place in a location that is not desirable, its mean they are not follow their parents. In this situation you had to work with parents first and then modify children.

I checked your css file and there is not even a single relative positioned parent. So i recommend you to edit your css file to this version and read the link i putted down below.

P.S If you didn't get what you was looking for please make and screen shot/jsfiddle of you situation.

```
<div class="container" >
    <ul class="imageBanner">
      <li>
        <span>Image 01</span>
        <div>
          <h3>Ahoy.</h3>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><span>Image 02</span>
        <div>
          <h3>Welcome.</h3>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><span>Image 03</span>
        <div>
          <h3>Bonjour.</h3>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS: (this is just part of css that changed/modified)

```
.container {height: 100vh;box-shadow: 0px 8px 5px #888888;background:#CCC;display:block;position: relative;width: 100%;}
.imageBanner {position: relative;display: block;width: 100%;height: 100%;padding: 0 0 0;margin: 0 0 0;}
.imageBanner li {position: absolute;display: block;width: 100%;height: 100%;top:0;left:0;}
.imageBanner li span {font-family:Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;text-align: center;width: 100%;height: 100%;position: absolute;top: 15%;color: #000000;background-size: cover;background-repeat: none;opacity: 0;z-index: 50;font-size: 2em;animation: imageAnimation 18s linear infinite 0s;}
.imageBanner li div {z-index: 1;position: absolute;top:0px;width: 100%;height: 100%;text-align: center;opacity: 0;animation: titleAnimation 18s linear infinite 0s;}
.imageBanner li div h3 {font-family:Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;background: #fff;font-size: 7em;color: rgb(46,105,163);padding: 0 0 0;margin: 0 0 0;line-height: 6em;}
```

[**CSS Pos Tutorials**](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/)
[**CSS Positions**](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

**Edit**
[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/BurnBin/pen/XzQRPW)

Comment: Unfortunately adding position:relative; causes the images to fail to operate properly (or fail to load but I'm assuming it's just a formatting issue). I'm sorry about the live example I'm currently working on an Apache server before I go find a hosting service; was hoping to make this block the front of my homepage as a transitioning Image/Caption slideshow.

Comment: @ThomasFiala If you be able to make a demo in codepen or something would be great. But seems there is more problem because when you have `position: absolute` in your child elements, its important they have a parent or grand parent with relative position. So if image is not getting visible means the structure is not standard. regards

Comment: [Here's](https://codepen.io/SpazSuper/pen/MORpPV) my current project on codepen; though it's not working the way it does on my apache server with the images; basically the bounds of the text are outside that of the table element (grey box) at the top where it should be constrained and where the text should cycle. when the window is resized the text moves off the screen. (or is already off the screen depending on screen size)

Comment: @ThomasFiala edited. Check my codepen. If this is what you asked for, please accept this post as an answer. regards

Comment: Unfortunately that's not exactly what I'm looking for; the text is still overflowing the .container DIV that houses the image list (as seen in the transition where the text overflows the drop shadow of the .container DIV. I'm hoping to define the space of the text container to the size and shape of the .container DIV so that the text (and the white background I put for reference) stays within the bounds of the dropshadow. (or bounds of .container DIV)

Comment: @ThomasFiala cant rly find out what result your are seeking for, if its not trouble for you i can do some changes if you made an image about final result that you try to achieve. Regards

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 markup will help you to understand center caption alignment.

*Here is a Basic Example:*

```css
.container {
  /* Full height*/
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 5px #888888;
  background: #ccc;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  height: 100% display: block;
}


/* Image Slideshow Banner */

.imageBanner li span {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: none;
  z-index: 0;
  animation: imageAnimation 18s linear infinite 0s;
}

.imageBanner li div {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: titleAnimation 18s linear infinite 0s;
}

.imageBanner li div h3 {
  font-family: Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 7em;
  color: #2e69a3;
  line-height: 6em;
}

.imageBanner li:nth-child(1) span {
  background-image: url("https://unsplash.it/1200/800");
}

.imageBanner li:nth-child(2) span {
  background-image: url("https://unsplash.it/1200/800");
  animation-delay: 6s;
}

.imageBanner li:nth-child(3) span {
  background-image: url("https://unsplash.it/1200/800");
  animation-delay: 12s;
}

.imageBanner li:nth-child(2) div {
  animation-delay: 6s;
}

.imageBanner li:nth-child(3) div {
  animation-delay: 12s;
}

@keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  35% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes titleAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  35% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="imageBanner">
    <li>
      <span></span>
      <div>
        <h3>Ahoy.</h3>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><span></span>
      <div>
        <h3>Welcome.</h3>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><span></span>
      <div>
        <h3>Bonjour.</h3>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to get the transitioning of the elements to work once I place the images in the list instead of the SPAN tag content. I also tried adding the text alignment to the H2 tag specifically and displaying the container as a block but it seems the caption's still outside the bounds of the parent container.

Comment: [Here's](https://codepen.io/SpazSuper/pen/MORpPV) my current project on codepen; though it's not working the way it does on my apache server with the images; basically the bounds of the text are outside that of the table element (grey box) at the top where it should be constrained and where the text should cycle. when the window is resized the text moves off the screen.

Comment: So where you want to add text in image? bottom of the image like caption?

Comment: I'm hoping to use the text as a caption yes. I was hoping to position it in the top 1/3 of the image in the center. The problem is the text overflows the container I've tried to define for the image and as such doesn't adjust to the window resize in the same way as the image.